# PHP remove ', ' from string if doesn't exist

Tags: php

I am running this code:

```
$stmt = $pdo_conn->prepare("SELECT * from admin where support_emails = :support_emails and logged = :logged and disabled = :disabled ");
        $stmt->execute(array(':support_emails' => 'Y', ':logged' => 'in', ':disabled' => ''));
        $records = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        if(count($records) > 0) {
            foreach($records as $records2) {
                if(filter_var($records2["email"], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
                    $SupportEmailList = $records2["email"].', '.$SupportEmailList;
                }
                if(!empty($SupportEmailList)) {
                    $SupportEmailList = substr($SupportEmailList, 0, -2); // removes last 2 characters (`, `) from end of string
                }
            }
        }
```

which returns

```
email1@domain1.com, email2@domain2.com
```

when i run in SQL

i have added:

```
if(!empty($SupportEmailList)) {
                    $SupportEmailList = substr($SupportEmailList, 0, -2); // removes last 2 characters (`, `) from end of string
                }
```

to remove the `', '` from the end of the string if the last result doesn't exist, but it seems to be creating the following:

```
email1@domain1.com, email2@domain2.c
```

rather than:

```
email1@domain1.com, email2@domain2.com
```

Comment: you want to add each emailadres to the string seperated by , ?

Comment: yeah basically create a string with all the email addresses returned from the database separated by a comma

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would suggest keeping your results in an array and use [implode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) (or join) to join them with a comma.

This way you don't have to deal with trailing comma issue.

```
$email_address = array();

foreach($records as $records2) {
    if(filter_var($records2["email"], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        array_push($email_address, $records2["email"]);
    }
}

$comma_separated_email_address = implode(",", $email_address);

echo $comma_separated_email_address ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [`trim()`](https://www.php.net/trim).  You can pass a list of characters as a second parameter to choose what you want to trim from the beginning/end of the string:

```
$example_1 = 'email1@domain1.com, email2@domain2.com';
$example_2 = 'email1@domain1.com, email2@domain2.com, ';

$example_1 = trim($example_1, ', ');
$example_2 = trim($example_2, ', ');

var_dump($example_1); // string(38) "email1@domain1.com, email2@domain2.com"
var_dump($example_2); // string(38) "email1@domain1.com, email2@domain2.com"

var_dump(explode(', ', $example_1));
// array(2) { [0]=> string(18) "email1@domain1.com" [1]=> string(18) "email2@domain2.com" }
```

Comment: `trim()` trims the characters (`, `) from the beginning and end of the String.  What did you want to do?  If you want to split by the `, ` try `explode()`.

Comment: trim is only for beginning and end of a string.

Comment: @SenseException I was just answering OP's question: *to remove the ', ' from the end of the string*..although it seems as though it was up to some interpretation.

Comment: I was answering a question about if trim is only removing ', ' from end. The question comment was removed :-)

Answer (score 0):

You could split your string with `explode` and `implode` again

```
$data = explode(',', $elements);
$cleanedData = implode(',', $data);
```

You could trim space in your data trimming all values in $data array

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($data); $i++)
    $data[$i] = trim($data[$i]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your question, remove ',' if it doesn't exist? anyway You should fetch your data using `PDO::FETCH_NUM`. This way you'll get an array of emails like `['email1@domail.com', 'email2@mail.com']` and then if you whant something like `'email1@domail.com, email2@mail.com'` use [implode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) to join the elements with a String.

Answer (score 0):

Do it:

```
$emails  = " email1@domain1.com , fsdfsdffdsffds , email2@domain2.com,sddsfsdsd ";
$emails = array_map('trim',explode(',',$emails));

$out = array_map(function($email){
                return (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) ? $email : null;
             },$emails);

$emails = implode(',',array_filter($out));
print_r($emails);
// email1@domain1.com,email2@domain2.com
```